# How do I optimize HHL algorithm in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, hhl-algorithm

How do I optimize HHL algorithm in Qiskit?

I tried to follow [this tutorial on HHL in Qiskit](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/legacy_tutorials/aqua/linear_systems_of_equations.ipynb). My project requires solving a very specific type of linear equations $Ax=b$ like the one below.

```
b = np.array( [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  2.25 ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   , -4.285,  0.   ])
A = np.array([[ 1.   ,  0.333,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
              [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
              [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
              [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.143,  1.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
              [-0.333, -1.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.333,  0.   ,  0.   ],
              [-0.25 , -1.5  , -0.25 ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
              [ 0.   , -0.562, -0.875, -0.562,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ],
              [ 0.   ,  0.   , -1.   , -0.143,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.143,  1.   ]])
```

However, I only obtain a fidelity of around 0.7 - 0.8, which is not good enough for what I would like to do.

I notice the tutorial has a function called `create_eigs` with input parameters `num_ancillae`, `num_time_slices`, `negative_evals`.

```
def create_eigs(matrix, num_ancillae, num_time_slices, negative_evals):
    ...
```

What are they really? And what are their appropriate values?

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer. The create_eigs function uses the Quantum Phase Estimation (QPE) algorithm to estimate the eigenvalues of your matrix. Here is what I can say about the input paramters:

num_ancilla: The number of ancillary qubits to use in the QPE algorithm. More qubits results in better precision for eigenvalue estimation but also greater depth for your circuit. See [section 3 of this tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-phase-estimation.html) to learn more about how it will increase your precision.

num_time_slices: I actually have no idea what this is and I stumbled across this question because I was looking for an answer.

negative_evals: This is a simple boolean response indicating if you have or expect negative eigenvalues. An input of "True" will increase the number of ancillary qubits by 1 and therefore lead to a circuit of greater depth.

If anyone could elaborate on what num_time_slices is exactly than I would appreciate it.